# How to get a page name using Selenium Webdriver (C#)?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get page title using Selenium C# Webdriver?

Comment: page name could also mean something like login.html and not necessarily the title

Answer (score 11):

Or I think that

```
driver.Title;
```

also works?

Answer (score 2):

driver.Title is the easy way to get the title of the page.  It returns a string.

```
string myTitle = driver.Title;
```

If you want the title as an IWebElement then you can also get it by searching the DOM.

```
IWebElement myTitle = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("title"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the title of the page by using: -driver.Title;

Below i have written a small test that can help you understand how it works..

```
public void someTest()
{
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
 String title=driver.Title;
}
```

Comment: how to verify the title after getting it.?