# <HTML> <head> <title> text empty with selenium Firefox webdriver

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Firefox 21 and C# WebDriver 2.33 on Windows 7. I'm baffled why the following test fails (which I have just to check my configuration is set up correctly).  This passes in other browsers.

```c#
[Test]
public void FirefoxDriverWorks()
{
    var firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    TestGoogleStillExists(firefoxDriver);
    firefoxDriver.Quit();
}

public void TestGoogleStillExists(IWebDriver webDriver)
{
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    var title = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("head title"));
    Assert.That(title.Text, Is.EqualTo("Google"));
}
```

Comment: whats the title.text u get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver's `text` function will only return text that is visible to the user on the page itself. The title text is not technically visible on the page (it is displayed in the title section of the chrome in the browser).

Instead, Selenium WebDriver has a method that will [return the title of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472026/how-to-get-a-page-name-using-selenium-webdriver-c) that you can use:

```
driver.Title;
```

So your code becomes:

```
public void TestGoogleStillExists(IWebDriver webDriver)
{
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    var title = webDriver.Title;
    Assert.That(title, Is.EqualTo("Google"));
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, this was a very recent change in behavior in the Firefox driver. Incidentally, the IE driver should behave the same way in 2.33, assuming you've updated your IEDriverServer.exe to 2.33.0.0. The Chrome driver will eventually exhibit the same behavior, but releases for chromedriver.exe lag the other drivers by a fair amount.