# Problems with E2E test with angularJS and protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

So I'm just curious about something... it appears that when doing e2e tests with Protractor and doing things like "expect(element(by.css('.test')).getText()).toBe('Some Text');" this only works for elements in the BODY section of the document and not the HEAD section.

For example I tinkered with the tutorial phonecatApp index.html so that it looks like this:

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title class="appTitle">Google Phone Gallery</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">

  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/animations.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="test">Some Text</div>

  <div class="view-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I added some simple tests to scenarios.js that look like this:

```
it('should set the title to "Google Phone Gallery"', function () {
  expect(element(by.css('.appTitle')).getText()).toBe('Google Phone Gallery');
});


it('should set the div.test to "Some Text"', function () {
  expect(element(by.css('.test')).getText()).toBe('Some Text');
});
```

The first test to check TITLE always fails with "Expected ' ' to be 'Google Phone Gallery'."  But the DIV test works fine.

Is there anything special required to check elements in the HEAD section or is this just something you can't do with Protractor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<HTML> <head> <title> text empty with selenium Firefox webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714782/html-head-title-text-empty-with-selenium-firefox-webdriver)

Comment: OK that explains things. I ended up finding another way to do my test. In my actual code rather than static text in my title tag I have an angular binding {{viewTitle}} that determines what the title text is. I was able to test this using the evaluate() method so my expect looks something like this: expect(element(by.css('title')).evaluate('viewTitle')).toBe("My Title");