# Python selenium find_element_by_css_selector() not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('title')
print content
```

I can't seem to get any content by any means(tag_name, class_name, name...)
What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Just this:<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4aff1f03-26fc-4ddb-9181-534d24ecd0d8", element="{5c5b4c91-740d-40d3-a888-c05a43a1d1e0}")>

Comment: Then it is working fine. You want to read the text then you should use `print content.text` With the WebElement you can do any of the actions mentioned [here] (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=webelement#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement)

Comment: Yes but now it returns nothing for the title

Comment: Can you try printing `content.tag_name`?

Comment: Have put in the details in my answer below. Please take a look. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code. The is element being identified correctly by your code.

```
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('title')
print content.tag_name
```

This should confirm that you have indeed located a web element with title tag. The content.text does not return anything since the title element is not part of the page itself. (Similar trouble discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717046/2599266) in Java)

If you're trying to print the title of the page, use the following driver field

```
print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct because you are trying to print out the literal web element, not the text contained within it. It is not an error, you're just not printing out the correct thing.

Change your last line to this:

```
print content.text
```

Comment: content.text does  not return the title of the page.

Comment: Why not just use `driver.title` if its the page title you're after? No need to go looking in the DOM.