# Selenium IE Page title is not working. Tried IWebDriver.Title

Tags: selenium, xpath

I asked this question last week and someone marked it as a duplicate. However the duplicate reference did not answer or give solution to my question.

I am trying to get the page title to a complicated html page. I am trying to get the 'By' locator used to find an element. This is the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>
 Smart Tracking System
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/desktopicon.ico" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/appstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/calendarstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/tabsstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>
```

When I copy the xpath from Firefox source code, it says the xpath is:
/html/head/title

I am using C# code to do the validation but I keep getting "LoadableComponentException..."
This is my C# code:

```
public class AccountsOverviewPage : CVALoadableComponent<AccountsOverviewPage>
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    private By textlabelPageHeader = By.XPath("//head[@class='title' and text()='Smart Tracking System']");

    public AccountsOverviewPage()
    {
        _driver = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IWebDriver>();
    }

    protected override void ExecuteLoad()
    {
    }

    protected override bool EvaluateLoadedStatus()
    {
        if (!CVAElements.WaitForElementOnPageLoad(_driver, textlabelPageHeader))
        {
            UnableToLoadMessage = "Could not load Accounts Overview page within the designated timeout period";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsAt()
    {
        return CVAElements.CheckElementIsVisible(_driver, textlabelPageHeader);
    }

}
```

I have even tried doing the validation by Id, and this time I used an element Id that I am sure is there:

```
private By textlabelPageHeader = By.Id("ctl00_Head1");
```

and still the validation failed. What am I not doing?? Please any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is how I am using the Driver.Title method:

```
public class AccountsOverviewPage : CVALoadableComponent<AccountsOverviewPage>
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    // error happens on this line:
    string textlabelPageHeader = _driver.Title;

    public string TextlabelPageHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return textlabelPageHeader;
        }

        set
        {
            textlabelPageHeader = value;
        }
    }



    public AccountsOverviewPage()
    {
        _driver = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<IWebDriver>();
    }

    protected override void ExecuteLoad()
    {
    }

    protected override bool EvaluateLoadedStatus()
    {
        if (!CVAElements.WaitForElementOnPageLoad(_driver, TextlabelPageHeader))
        {
            UnableToLoadMessage = "Could not load Accounts Overview page within the designated timeout period";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsAt()
    {
        return CVAElements.CheckElementIsVisible(_driver, TextlabelPageHeader);
    }
```

and I getting error: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" here

```
string textlabelPageHeader = _driver.Title;
```

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying to access incase its a public IP? Also mention the steps you are trying to do.

Comment: `driver.Title` returns the actual value of `<title>...</tile>`. Use it instead. Why do you need to handle `title` element?

Comment: @Dev, unfortunately I cannot share the URL and also that page will not be accessible until you log in with registered credentials. The steps are: Open IE > go to the URL > Login user and then validate the title. All the steps pass except the last one

Comment: @Andersson, I tried that and it did not work. Unless I am not doing it the right way. Do you mind providing example?

Comment: As I understand you're trying to wait until `head` or `title`  element is visible. But `<head>` and elements inside `<head>` cannot be visible as they are not part of page `<body>`

Comment: @Andersson, yes. I have a separate method where I create wait interval to 30 seconds:                                                                                                     public const int DefaultTimeout = 30;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a page name using Selenium Webdriver (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472026/how-to-get-a-page-name-using-selenium-webdriver-c)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Please provide an [mcve]. We don't need all your code, just the relevant bits and especially the full error message.

Comment: So, did you google the error message? `Driver.Title` works fine. You are using it incorrectly. Google the error message, read some of the results, and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to access - a page title - is not a web element.  It's a property of the web page itself.  In Selenium, you access the page title by:

```
String pageTitle = _driver.getTitle();
```

I program in Java, so that might not be the correct syntax for C#

Comment: it seems that OP search for solution in `C#` not in `Java`

Comment: I caught that a sec before you posted, but the idea would be the same, I would think - just assign the title to a string through Selenium?

Comment: In `C#` it looks like `Driver.Title`. However, according to previous ticket for some reason OP refuse to use this approach

Comment: The page title IS a web element... that's where the title comes from. It's displayed in OPs post and HTML references. I don't know why OP wants to get the element when he can just do `Driver.Title`.

Comment: @jeffc, I have mentioned before that I have tried that and it did not work

Comment: @Geezus Well you referenced another question but this is a new question. This question needs to contain all the info that we need to answer it. You need to post the code you have tried, the results, error messages, etc. in this question so we can answer it.

Comment: @JeffC, I have added the code for how I use the Driver.Title in the original post. I immediately get error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to OpenQA.Selenium.By